# Ionic "Quiz App"

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I'm sort of a beginner, so I'm not that good with code at all, pardon me.

Here's my file in question:
https://github.com/SamuelChan123/QuizApp/tree/master/testApp3.11/www

I'm trying to make a "quiz app" which basically will take in information from fieldbook (which is similar to Excel)...the fieldbook link is here:

https://api.fieldbook.com/v1/56be4f73bf3e5b030029d62a/quiz_app_q_a/1

I know how to set up the link so that once you click on one button, it can send you to another page, but I have no idea how to set it up so that it pulls data from fieldbook, and when you click on the right page, you get sent to the "correct" page, while if you get it wrong, it displays a "wrong" page. How can I do this? Right now, my fieldbook has it so that I have a a1right, a2right, etc. for each question, but how to determine the right answer from the wrong one?
I'm having a tough time with this. Thanks in advance!

Here's a code sample: I have 4 buttons and the last one, when clicked, will bring you to the "you are correct" page. How do I determine which one this will be and pull information from the fieldbook telling me which one is right so I can display either a correct or incorrect page?

```
 <ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title>{{film.question}}</ion-nav-title>
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header">
        <div>
            <button class="button button-full button-royal">
                {{film.a1}}
            </button>
            <button class="button button-full button-royal">
                {{film.a2}}
            </button>
            <button class="button button-full button-energized">
                {{film.a3}}
            </button>
            <button class="button button-full button-energized" ui-sref="answerTitle">
                {{film.a4}}<br>{{film.a4right}}
            </button>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Months later, I finally figured it out. :) Code for services:

.factory('LaunchService', ['$http','$q',function($http,$q){

```
return {
    getLaunches:function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get("https://api.fieldbook.com/v1/57573878f5d7a40300bcf093/launch_app/").then(function(res) {
            //console.dir(res.data.results);
            /*var results = res.data.results.map(function(result) {
                result.id = result.url;
                return result;
            });*/
            deferred.resolve(res.data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    },
    getLaunch:function(id) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get("https://api.fieldbook.com/v1/57573878f5d7a40300bcf093/launch_app/" + id).then(function(res) {
            //console.dir(res.data);
            deferred.resolve(res.data);
        });
        ionic.Platform.fullScreen(true, false);    
        return deferred.promise;

    }   
};
```

}]);